# HDFS Date partition directory loop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cassandra, hdfs, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a HDFS Directory as below.

```
/user/staging/app_name/2022_05_06
```

Under such a directory I have around 1000 part files.

I want to loop each of the part file and start loading them into cassandra,the volume of the entire directory is around  50 Billion.

This is very huge to process in a single shot,hence the idea was to read the individual part files and start loading them one by one in Append Mode.

Can anyone help in the approach?

Comment: as I mentioned in the comment to another question - most probably you have problem with Cassandra itself. In this case looping through individual files won't help much